# How to create a 16-bit Video with cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to know is there any way to record 16bit depth image as video in opencv or other library? As my project need depth image which is 16bit per pixel, I need to record a sequence of raw depth image pixel data.
Is there any way or alternative to achieve this idea?
Currently, I'm using opencv 2.4.11 in c++
Thanks

Comment: do you want to "play" them or just store and recover? do you need lossless compression?

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes I need to store them and recover. And i also need lossless compression
I try CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'B', ' ') codec, but it store depth image data as 8bit 3 channels which is not what i need.

Comment: if compression isnt important i would suggest to write in a raw file. i dont think many codecs support 1 channel 16 bit images and maybe opencv doesnt support any

Comment: e.g. png compression was too slow on my machine when I worked with kinect (25fps) so i just wrote (big) raw files...

Comment: Thanks for reply, I decide to record as ONI file and extract frame from ONI.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I decided to record as ONI file and extract frame from ONI.